# Uniqueness (up to natural isomorphism) of equivalences

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ and $D$ be two categories and let $F:C \to D$ and $G:D \to C$ be two functors forming an equivalence of categories. Given another functor $G':D \to C$ that together with $F$ forms an equivalence, is there necessarily a natural isomorphism between $G$ and $G'$?

Comment: as equivalences are adjoint functors with units and counits being isomorphisms, the triangle identities should give you in a classical way a natural isomorphism between $G$ and $G'$

Comment: Could you please explain this in some more detail. I do not see how the triangle identities imply an isomorphism between $G$ and $G'$.

Comment: Write it all down and build it yourself:  there are natural isos $G(X) \to F(X) \to G'(X)$ by assumption, and in reverse.  Check all definitions.